# How do I add CSS to only one element?

Tags: css

I have 2 buttons on my website that have the same class of `.ow-button-base`. What I'm trying to do is make it so that one of these buttons does not appear when the website is loaded on a mobile device. This is the code that I'm using now:

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 640px) {
  .ow-button-base {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

When I use this BOTH buttons do not appear when the website is loaded on a mobile device. How do I make it so only one does not appear?

Comment: @legionar ok my bad I didn't see your answer till I posted my comment. I took it off.

Answer (score 3):

Simply add to one of the button (which you want to show on mobile device) ID, f.e `my_button2`:

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 640px) {
  .ow-button-base {
    display: none;
  }

  #my_button2  {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

And your buttons:

```
<button class="ow-button-base" />
<button class="ow-button-base" id="my_button2" />
```

Then the second button will be shown also for mobile device.

Comment: How do I change the id for my buttons though? I'm using wordpress, how can I directly change the html of the webpage? I'm very new to css and html

Comment: Post your HTML, and I will show you. Simply add `id="my_button2"` to your second button.

Answer (score 0):

You could target it using the `:last-of-type` blocker.

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 640px) {
.ow-button-base:last-of-type {
    display: none;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like them to have the same class, use a selector that will find a specific instance:

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 640px) {
  .ow-button-base:nth-of-type(2) { // select the second instance
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: This will not work, if both buttons have not the same parent.